# AMD catalyst driver 12.1

Tags: ati

AMD catalyst driver version 12.1 has been released. Is suspend or sleep problem still there? I checked 11.10 and 11.11. Performance is ok but after suspend laptop does not wake up. Is 12.1 fix this? If yes i will try it otherwise wait....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series, the latest ATI/AMD drivers, and Gnome-Shell. Suspend works for me only if I'm not runnning Wine or Qt application. It takes like 3 minutes sometimes, but works.

So the suspend bug is still there ...

Comment: so Catalyst is not ready for ubuntu. SAD..

Answer (score 1):

In my case with my ASUS 1015B Netbook which has the hybrid AMD C50 CPU which has integrated ATI6350 graphics, suspend doesn't work even with C6 turned off in BIOS, I have to take the battery out to revive the system.

Comment: Hold on power button for times to shutdown the system. It works for me. (Acer laptop with AMD 6320HD graphics)